# how to get SUM of a set of values from a table then the MAX of those values and echo the 5 highest values

Tags: mysql

Forewarning ,I'm a total newbie so be gentle.I need to get the SUM of *qty* from a set of values and then the top 5 MAX *sum qty* from that list. But I need to leave out a NULL value from final list.

Comment: If  my answer helps you, feel free to upvote and/or accept this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT game_name,
       max(total) AS total  
FROM ( select game_name,
              sum(qty) AS total
       FROM sales
       GROUP BY game_name
     ) AS RANK
where game_name is not null
group by game_name
order by total desc limit 5 ;
```

It will remove any `null` game, order by total descending and it gives you the first 5 rows.

Answer (score 1):

I would do this without a subquery as:

```
select game_name, sum(qty) AS total 
from sales
where game_name is not null
group by game_name
order by total desc
limit 5;
```